# cannot connect schema registry kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run confluent schema registry via docker image (on Mac os Catalina and Docker version 19.03.12)

```
docker run --network="host" -e \
    SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=localhost:2181 \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=localhost \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
```

I'm running zookeper (3.5.8) and kafka server no the localmachine (no docker). The above picks (3.5.8 client of zookeper).  However schema-registry is unable to connect.

```
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] 
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - 
Socket error occurred: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181: Connection refused
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] 
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - 
Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. 
Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

I also tried mapping the port, instead of running it in the host network but have the same result

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -e \
    SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=host.docker.internal:2181 \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=localhost \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 \
    -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
```

Any ideas?   Kafka BTW is running happily I can consume and produce messages.

Comment: Why not use Docker Compose to start everything? https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo/blob/6.0.0-post/docker-compose.yml Or `brew install confluent-platform` and start everything without Docker? The problem is that `--network=host` doesn't work on Mac and you should generally never trust `host.docker.internal` for anything

Comment: @OneCricketeer Unfortunately, brew install doesn't work anymore.   But yeah, I see your point. I probably install everything locally. I just wanted to leverage my existing install, data, etc.

Comment: Should work according to https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/confluent-platform

Comment: @OneCricketeer you get "confluent-platform has been disabled because it does not have an OSI license!"

Comment: Ah. Disabled 7 days ago... My bad